# IntelliSense not working well with Python in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

In Visual Studio 2015, while programming in C#, IntelliSense menu is automatically poping out when I press a character. Like in this image

[image: C# intellisense]

But the same is not happening when I use Python. The menu pops out only when I press `ctr + space` or when I press `.`.

Is it like this in PTVS or am I missing something?

I am using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update
  1
- PTVS Version 2.2.31124.00